# Automatic ID based on dropdown reference in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Google Sheet I have a dropdown in col D with four options:

- YELLOW
- BROWN
- RED
- BLUE

Now, I would to create a column to generate an auto ID which increases by +1 always based on the dropdown by adding the letter corresponding to the ID.

And so for YELLOW or BROWN the letter X, for RED or BLUE the letter Y.

How could I proceed with Apps Script?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GZFnUqeywqNN9tmQh-w3S5ioVN7nPv2S7cmLiWzqQ1g/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user did not put any effort into solving the issue himself or did not show his efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this code in the script editor and save it

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const colors = ["YELLOW", "BROWN", "BLUE", "RED"];
  const ind = colors.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName()== 'Foglio1' && ind > -1 && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && !e.oldValue) {
    const idLetter = ind < 2 ? "X" : "Y";
    const idNumber = getId(sh, idLetter);
    const target = e.range.offset(0, -3);
    if(!target.getValue()) target.setValue(idNumber + idLetter);
  }
}

function getId(sh, idLetter) {
  const last = sh.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter( r => r[0].includes(idLetter)).pop();
  return last ? Number(last[0].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')) + 1 : 1;
}
```

After saving, go back to the spreadsheet (tab 'Foglio1') and see if the ID appears after selecting a value in column D.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have also tried with a similar code I was writing.
I have integrated some line of your code and it seems to work.
Thanks :)